# Change checkbox color with click of button to fade from top to bottom one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

How can I create a "progress bar" style (almost as if it's loading) fade from top to bottom from the original color into the new color for these **checked** checkboxes one at a time in their perspective checked order and not all at once after clicking the button?

My CSS transition is not working.

Here is an example of my code. I hope I was able to explain it well enough.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("table").toggleClass("alternative");
});
```

```css
table.example1, table.example1 th, table.example1 td {
    border: 3px solid grey;
    max-width: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 6px 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    background-color: #3e618b;
    outline: 0;
}
.alternative input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    -moz-transition: height .10s ease-in;
    -o-transition: height .10s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: height .10s ease-in;
    transition: height .10s ease-in;
    background-color: #5093e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="example1" style="width:40%;" align='center'>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk" value="1">
          <label for="chk1">&nbsp; 1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk"value="2">
        <label for="chk2">&nbsp; 2</label>
    </td>
</tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="chk" value="3">
              <label for="chk3">&nbsp; 3</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk4"name="chk" value="4">
            <label for="chk4">&nbsp; 4</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk5"name="chk"value="5">
            <label for="chk5">&nbsp; 5</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk6"name="chk"value="6">
            <label for="chk6">&nbsp; 6</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk7"name="chk"value="7">
            <label for="chk7">&nbsp; 7</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk8"name="chk"value="8">
            <label for="chk8">&nbsp; 8</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>   

<button>Changes checked checkbox color</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but since you're only modifying the `background-color` property, you want your transition to monitor that (not height). Also, putting it on the non-checked input allows it to happen when it transitions from that to your checked style.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("table").toggleClass("alternative");
});
```

```css
table.example1, table.example1 th, table.example1 td {
    border: 3px solid grey;
    max-width: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 6px 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    transition: background-color 2s ease-in;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    background-color: #3e618b;
    outline: 0;
}
.alternative input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    -moz-transition: background-color .10s ease-in;
    -o-transition: background-color .10s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .10s ease-in;
    transition: background-color 2s ease-in;
    background-color: #5093e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="example1" style="width:40%;" align='center'>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk" value="1">
          <label for="chk1">&nbsp; 1</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk"value="2">
        <label for="chk2">&nbsp; 2</label>
    </td>
</tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="chk" value="3">
              <label for="chk3">&nbsp; 3</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk4"name="chk" value="4">
            <label for="chk4">&nbsp; 4</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk5"name="chk"value="5">
            <label for="chk5">&nbsp; 5</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk6"name="chk"value="6">
            <label for="chk6">&nbsp; 6</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk7"name="chk"value="7">
            <label for="chk7">&nbsp; 7</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk8"name="chk"value="8">
            <label for="chk8">&nbsp; 8</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>   

<button>Changes checked checkbox color</button>
```

Comment: I am just looking to have it fade in from the top to bottom after the button has been clicked. How would you do it so it's each checked checkbox at a time and not all at once? Like if the user checked boxes 1, 4, 7. How can I make it where it'll start at 1, once that's done, then it'll change the color of 4, then 7?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below.

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".overlay").css('top', '0px');
});
```

```css
table.example1, table.example1 th, table.example1 td {
    border: 3px solid grey;
    max-width: 200px;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3e618b;
  top: -60px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  transition:top 1s linear;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    transition: top 1s linear;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .overlay{
    top: 0;
}
.alternative input[type=checkbox]:checked + label{
    -moz-transition: height .10s ease-in;
    -o-transition: height .10s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: height .10s ease-in;
    transition: height 1s ease-in;
    background-color: #5093e4;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="example1" style="width:40%;" align='center'>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" name="chk" value="1">
        <label for="chk1">&nbsp; 1</label>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" name="chk"value="2">
        <label for="chk2">&nbsp; 2</label>
        <div class="overlay"></div>
    </td>
</tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk3" name="chk" value="3">
              <label for="chk3">&nbsp; 3</label>
                      <div class="overlay"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk4"name="chk" value="4">
            <label for="chk4">&nbsp; 4</label>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk5"name="chk"value="5">
            <label for="chk5">&nbsp; 5</label>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk6"name="chk"value="6">
            <label for="chk6">&nbsp; 6</label>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk7"name="chk"value="7">
            <label for="chk7">&nbsp; 7</label>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="chk8"name="chk"value="8">
            <label for="chk8">&nbsp; 8</label>
                    <div class="overlay"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>   

<button>Changes checked checkbox color</button>
```

Comment: How can this overlay happen when I click on the button and not on the check box?

Comment: Okay, in your example, the overlay is happening as the user checks the box and then when the button is clicked, all the checkboxes get the overlay, doesn't matter if they were checked or not. What I am looking for is after the user checks the checkbox (which turns to the color #3e618b), then the user clicks the button and only the checked checkboxes get the overlay (color #5093e4). Only after the user has checked the box and pressed the button should the overlay appear on only the checked boxes. How do I do that?